# How can I solve the issue 'ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer' in python

Tags: python, pandas

Following is the code part that the above issue appeared.

```
df["Height (cm)"]= df["Height (cm)"].astype(int)
```

The Dtype of "Height (cm)" was initially 'object' and the missing values of it were replaced with *np.nan*.
Then I tried to execute the above code to convert Height into an integer type, but ended up by having the error **'ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer'**.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: How do you want to handle missing values? Want them to be replaced by `0` or any other `int` value? If that's the case then use `df.replace` to replace all `NaN` and cast to `int`

Comment: want to replace missing values by an int value

Comment: Try `df["Height (cm)"].astype('Int64')` (notice the capital "I" in "Int") - this dtype can handle NaN. Also works with `"Int32"`, `"Int16"`, ... etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to say what you want to do with nans. You can either drop those rows ([`df.dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)) or replace nans with something else (`0` for instance: [`df.fillna(0)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html))

```
df["Height (cm)"]= df["Height (cm)"].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Int64` instead

```
df["Height (cm)"]= df["Height (cm)"].astype('Int64')
```

It can handle NaN values.

Comment: It should be small int64 instead of Int64 :

df["Height (cm)"]= df["Height (cm)"].astype('int64')